# What are the six original sons of Israel that Exodus 28 speaks off?

Tags: history

As I was reading about the garment Aaron needed to wear I came across this and was confused because I have always read about the 12 tribes and how God used each Jacobs children as a tribe.  Please help me as I am trying to get wise in the Lord. Thank You

Comment: That appears to be an allusion to the children produced by Rachael and Leah, while vying for Jacobs affections. Other than that I can find no other reasoning for designation of an *original sons*. That is the only Scriptural basis I find for dividing the twelve tribes in groups. I also hope for someone to give another answer, since I also have pondered that designation.

Comment: @BYE Are you trying to clarify the question or provide an answer?

Comment: What translation are you using, and which specific verse mentions "original sons"?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast neither just making a comment.

Answer (score 7):

The “original sons” the passage speaks of refers to all twelve sons of Israel, since it reads as follows from Exodus 28:9–10:

> “Take two onyx stones, and engrave on them the names of the tribes of Israel. Six names will be on each stone, arranged in the order of the births of the original sons of Israel.”

This is from the New Living Translation, which was the first English translation I found to include the phrase “original sons,” but other translations might be clearer, such as the same in the ESV:

> “You shall take two onyx stones, and engrave on them the names of the sons of Israel, six of their names on the one stone, and the names of the remaining six on the other stone, in the order of their birth.”

Comment: Unless there was another reference to “original sons” in Exodus 28 you meant?

Comment: Welcome, and nice answer! Thanks for contributing. If you haven't already done so, I hope you'll take a minute to take the [tour] and learn [how this site is different from others](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576).

Comment: @greychr In Ch. 28 in the NLT,  "original" only appears once, in v 10. "sons" appears 7 times, five referring to Aaron's sons. Verse 10 refers to all twelve, as you explain. Verse 21 is explicitly "twelve sons".

Comment: @disciple Indeed, Exodus 28 contains multiple references to “sons,” some referring to Aaron’s sons and some to Israel’s sons. I’ve updated my answer to include the clarification. Thank you for helping clarify that.